# Strange seg fault arrasing from adding another variable to structure

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Here is my structure:

```
typedef struct termNode{
    char term[41];
    int matched;
    struct termNode *next;
} termNode;
```

It works fine with this code:

```
int add_term_to_list(char term[41]){
    int i = 0;  
    termNode *tmp = NULL;
    if(headTerm == NULL){
        if(create_head(term) != 0)
             return 1;
        else 
             return 0;
    }
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(termNode*));
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return 1;
    while(term[i] != '\n'){
        tmp -> term[i] = term[i];
        i++;
    }
    tmp -> term[i] = 0;
    tmp -> matched = 0;
    tmp -> next = NULL;
    currTerm -> next = tmp;
    currTerm = tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

However, if i add another variable to the structure:

```
typedef struct termNode{
        char term[41];
        int matched;
        int size;
        struct termNode *next;
    } termNode;
```

Then I get a segfault when I try to run. This is the only change in my code. Does anyone know why this happens?

I update the code -> make clean -> make -> run and I get segfault.

Comment: `tmp = malloc(sizeof(termNode*));` -->> `tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);`. Voila! (you are allocating space for a pointer, should be for the object where it points to)

Comment: Well that is very helpful, but I have no idea why it works. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Add `printf("size := %zu -->> %zu\n" , sizeof (termNode *), sizeof *tmp );` to the program, and you will see.

Comment: Thanks again, makes alot more sense now.